# ML on "Adult data set"(dataset) from archive.ics... whith KNeighborsClassifier wont run

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use Machine learning to guess if a person has an income of over or under 50k using [this](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Adult) data set. I think the code does not work because the data set contains strings. When I use a shorter data set containing 4 instead of 14 variables(and with numbers) the code works. What am I doing wrong?

```
# Load libraries
import pandas
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.svm import SVC

# Load dataset
url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data"
names = ['age', 'workclass', 'fnlwgt', 'education', 'education-num', 'marital-status', 'occupation', 'relationship', 'race', 'sex', 'capital-gain', 'capital-loss', 'hours-per-week', 'native-country', 'income']
dataset = pandas.read_csv(url, names=names)


# Split dataset
array = dataset.values
X = array[:,0:14]
Y = array[:,14]


X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=validation_size, random_state=seed)


knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
knn.fit(X_train, Y_train)
predictions = knn.predict(X_validation)

print(accuracy_score(Y_validation, predictions))
print(confusion_matrix(Y_validation, predictions))
print(classification_report(Y_validation, predictions))
```

Comment: What is the error you're receiving?

Comment: I think this is the error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' Private'

Comment: Sounds like your hunch was right, then. The model doesn't work out of the box with string data

Comment: Do you know a model that works with stings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For columns that contain categorical strings, you should transform them to one hot encoding using the function:

`dataset = pd.get_dummies(dataset, column=[my_column1, my_column2, ...])`

Where `my_column1, my_colum2, ...`are the column names containing the categorical strings. Be careful, it changes the number of columns you have in your dataframe. Thus, change your split of `X` accordingly.

[Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)  is the link to the documentation.

Comment: That's sounds like a smart idea. But when i use pd.get_dummies(X) I get this error Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional

Comment: My bad, you should perform the get_dummies on the dataframe 'dataset' and not X. I modified the answer...

Comment: I might be stupid but I can't get it to work, and I don't really get what I need to do.

Comment: Thanks I think I got it to work now. At least I don't get any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a really simple example from your dataset.

Looking at `dataset['income'].nunique()` (produces `2`), we can see you have two classes you're trying to predict. You're on the right track with taking the classification route (although there are different methodological arguments to be made as to whether this problem is better suited for a continuous regression approach, but save that for another day).

Say you want to use `age` and `education` to predict whether someone's income is above $50k. Let's try it out:

```py
X = dataset[['age', 'education']]
y = dataset['income']

model = KNeighborsClassifier()
model.fit(X, y)
```

This Exception should be raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/jake/Documents/assets/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/base.py", line 891, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, "csr", multi_output=True)
  File "/Users/jake/Documents/assets/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 756, in check_X_y
    estimator=estimator)
  File "/Users/jake/Documents/assets/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 567, in check_array
    array = array.astype(np.float64)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' Bachelors'
```

What if we tried with just `age`?

```py
X = dataset[['age']]
y = dataset['income']

model = KNeighborsClassifier()
model.fit(X, y)
```

Hey! That works! So there's something unique about the `education` column that we need to account for. You've noticed this above - scikit-learn (and many other ML packages - though not all) don't operate off of strings. So we need to do something like "one-hot" encoding - creating *k* columns, where *k* represents the number of unique values in your categorical, "string" column (again, there's a methodological question as to whether you include *k*-1 or *k* features, but read up on the dummy-variable trap for more info to that end), where each column is composed of 1s and 0s - a 1 if the case/observation in a particular row has that *k*th attribute, a 0 if not.

There are many ways of doing this in Python:

`pandas.get_dummies`:

```py
dummies = pandas.get_dummies(dataset['education'], prefix='education')
```

Here's a sample of `dummies`:

```
>>> dummies
       education_ 10th  education_ 11th  education_ 12th  education_ 1st-4th  education_ 5th-6th  ...  education_ HS-grad  education_ Masters  education_ Preschool  education_ Prof-school  education_ Some-college
0                    0                0                0                   0                   0  ...                   0                   0                     0                       0                        0
1                    0                0                0                   0                   0  ...                   0                   0                     0                       0                        0
2                    0                0                0                   0                   0  ...                   1                   0                     0                       0                        0
3                    0                1                0                   0                   0  ...                   0                   0                     0                       0                        0
4                    0                0                0                   0                   0  ...                   0                   0                     0                       0                        0
5                    0                0                0                   0                   0  ...                   0                   1                     0                       0                        0
6                    0                0                0                   0                   0  ...                   0                   0                     0                       0                        0
7                    0                0                0                   0                   0  ...                   1                   0                     0                       0                        0
8                    0                0                0                   0                   0  ...                   0                   1                     0                       0                        0
9                    0                0                0                   0                   0  ...                   0                   0                     0                       0                        0
```

Now we can use this `education` feature like so:

```py
dataset = dataset.join(dummies)
X = dataset[['age'] + list(dummies)]
y = dataset['income']

model = KNeighborsClassifier()
model.fit(X, y)
```

Hey, that worked!

Hopefully that helps to answer your question. There are tons of ways to perform one-hot encoding (e.g. through a list comprehension or `sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder`). I'd suggest you read more on "feature engineering" before progressing with your model-building - feature engineering is one of the most important parts of the ML process.